# how to transform a list of list of tuples into an np array where each element is a tuple in python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to transform in python a list of list of tuples in an np array of tuples.

for example, right now i have :

```
[[(a,b),(b,c),(d,e)]
[(f,g),(h,i),(j,k)]]
```

and i need numpy array of tuples  :

`[[(a,b) (b,c) (d,e)]
 [(f,g) (h,i) (j,k)]]`

And the shape would be (2,3)

Comment: is the datatype tuple important for you or a list will suffice?

Comment: yes the datatype tuple is important

Comment: otherwise `np.asarray()` would have been okay!

Comment: What's the `dtype` supposed to be?  What are you going to do with it?

Comment: dtype of my array is supposed to be a tuple. i need my data to stay as a tuple after converting my list of list into an array

Comment: I think what @hpaulj means is what are data types inside your tules? i.e. what is the data type of `a` and `b` and is it consistant for all tuples?

Comment: It is float numbers for all tuples

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but you have very careful with dtype.

```
In [4]: l = [[(0.0, 1.0), (3.0, 4.1)], [(5.4, 6.6), (7.3, 8.8)] ]                                        

In [5]: np.asarray(l, dtype=np.dtype('f, f'))                                                            
Out[5]: 
array([[(0. , 1. ), (3. , 4.1)],
       [(5.4, 6.6), (7.3, 8.8)]], dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

As you can see with `np.dtype('f, f')` you can only have two elements inside tuple

You can read more about it here : [Structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)

Comment: But when i do that, if i do array[0] it will give me the whole row and not the first tuple

Comment: since its a 2d array you have to do `array[0, 0]`